# awk to rename files in directory based on string match in another file

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to rename all `.txt` files in a directory based on a match to a column in a `file`. That is the string before the the `.txt` will be an exact match to `$2` of `file`,
the text file is then renamed with the `$1` value. he `awk` does execute, but not with the desired result. Thank you :).

**current directory structure**

```
123_1_000.txt
456_2_101.txt
789_3_200.txt
```

**file**

```
aaa 123_1
bbb 456_2
ccc 789_3
```

**awk**

```
ls *.txt | awk -vvar=$2 '{f=$1 ; sub($2,var); print "mv", f, $0 } ' file
```

**current**

```
mv aaa 123_1 aaa
mv bbb 456_2 bbb
mv ccc 789_3 ccc
```

**desired directory**

```
aaa_000.txt
bbb_101.txt
ccc_200.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate `ls *.txt` in my environment:

```
$ cat directory.list
123_1.txt
456_2.txt
789_3.txt
```

One `awk` idea:

```
cat directory.list | 
awk '
FNR==NR { map[$2]=$1; next }                               # needs additional work if either filename contains embedded spaces, newlines, odd characters
        { split($0,a,".")                                  # needs additional work if filename contains more than one period
          if (a[1] in map)
             print "mv \"" $0 "\" \"" map[a[1]] ".txt\""   # add double quote wrappers in case filenames contain white space, though OP will need to improve/fix earlier map[] and split() operations to support embedded white space
        }
' file -                                                   # the hyphen says to read stdin as the 2nd input file to the awk script
```

This generates:

```
mv "123_1.txt" "aaa.txt"
mv "456_2.txt" "bbb.txt"
mv "789_3.txt" "ccc.txt"
```

**NOTES:**

- this doesn't address the (obvious ?) issues of processing `ls` output (eg, filenames with odd characters, embedded linefeeds, etc)
- this doesn't actually perform the `mv` command (I'm just repeating what OP's current code does); to have `awk` perform the actual `mv` will require issuing a `system(...)` call; if OP has issues getting a `system(...)` call to work I'd recommend a new question
- this is one of those operations where a `bash` loop may be easier (eg, load `file` into an associative array and then process `ls/find` output with a `while/read` loop)

Comment: I am not sure what `directory.txt` is.  Is that the path to the directory with the`.txt` files in it. Thank you :).

Comment: `directory.list` (renamed) is just a file containing what your `ls *.txt` generates; `cat directory.list` == (your) `ls *.txt`; you should be able to replace `cat directory.list` (in my answer) with `ls *.txt`; I was too lazy to create a new test directory and then create 3 files with the same 3 names as in your sample input

Comment: I updated the input files and need to match on a pattern. That is the `.txt` files will have a subset (up to the last` _` in them. I tried a wildcard in the `map[a[1]] ".txt\"` and that gave a `syntax error bash: {: command not found -bash: next: command not found -bash: syntax error near unexpected token $0,a,"."' -bash: syntax error near unexpected token (' -bash: syntax error near unexpected token }`... I also tried storing the ls as a variable then `echo $i | awk '{sub(/([_^]*:){2}/,"")}1` but that printed the entire filename not the subset. Thank you :).

Comment: @justaguy at this point you're modifying the original question which in turn negates the answer(s) posted so far; normal (SO) procedure, especially when 3+months have gone by and the original Q has an accepted A, is to ask a new question; I'd recommend you rollback the latest update to the question (so the current answer still applies), then ask a new question, making sure to provide sample inputs, (correct) expected output, your latest coding attempt, and the (wrong) output generated by your code